# $wpdb returns no results with SELECT query

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a custom table on a wordpress database. I am inserting rows from my custom plugin but I canot select from this table. Select return always nothing.
The insert that is working fine is

```
   <?php
  global $wpdb;
     $wpdb->insert( 
'wp_SimParts', 
array( 
    'ProductName' => 'testname', 
    'ProductPrice' => 123,
            'ProductDescription' => 'testdescription',  
    'ProductImage' => 'testimage',
    'CategoryID' => 3
   ), 
 array( 
    '%s', 
    '%f',
    '%s', 
    '%s',
    '%d'
   ) 
 );

  ?>
```

When I try to select from this table I am taking nothing

```
<?php       
    global $wpdb;
    if(isset($_POST['search_product']))
    {
    $mytestproducts = $wpdb->get_results(
    "
    SELECT id, ProductName
    FROM $wpdb->wp_SimParts

    "
    );
       ?>
     <?php
    foreach($mytestproducts as  $mytestproduct)
    {
     ?>         
        <tr>
   <?php
        echo"<td>".$mytestproduct->ProductName."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$mytestproduct->id."</td>";
      ?>
        </tr>
      <?php
    }
    }
    ?>
```

If I try to select from posts I am taking normally results.

Comment: Try once with concat php $mytestproducts = $wpdb->get_results( "  SELECT id, ProductName FROM ".$wpdb->wp_SimParts);

Comment: still not getting results. Is it possible to be issue that I am declaring the global $wpdb; two times? the one in the insert and the next on select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object variable **$wpdb->wp_SimParts** is not set for **$wpdb**. It is table name.

Change your query to this:

```
$mytestproducts = $wpdb->get_results(
  "SELECT id, ProductName
  FROM wp_SimParts"
);
```

Comment: Yes you are correct you fixed my issue, thank you. I mark your answer as the correct answer. Please tell me what was my false?

Comment: I've written it in first sentence of my answer. You used $wpdb->wp_SimParts which is not defined object variable. You can use only [these variables](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) (find them below "Tables" heading), otherwise you have to specify table name. In your case it is 'wp_SimParts' or' {$wpdb->prefix}SimParts'